# OCAML - Adding a tuple to a tuple list

Tags: ocaml

I am actually stuck in adding a tuple in a list of tuple.
Here is my code.

```
let rec start_of_pattern = fun c index acc patterns n -> match patterns with
  | [] -> acc
  | h::t -> start_of_pattern c index [(Char.escaped c, index, h, n)]@acc t (n+1)
```

I tried also this:

```
let rec start_of_pattern = fun c index acc patterns n -> match patterns with
  | [] -> acc
  | h::t -> start_of_pattern c index (Char.escaped c, index, h, n)::acc t (n+1)
```

I want to add to "acc" a tuple of 4 elements (string, int, string, int). c is a char, index a int, acc normally tuple list, patterns a string list and n a int.

I have this error:

[first version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT7HQ.png)

[second version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCyDe.png)

I hope u guys can help me. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Please paste errors into the question, instead of posting pictures. People with vision issues may not be able to read the pictures, and other people running into similar errors can't find your pictures by Googling the error-message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function application in OCaml has high precedence. So this expression:

```
f x@y z
```

Is parsed like this:

```
(f x) @ (y z)
```

Looking at your first attempt, it seems to me you need to parenthesize like this:

```
start_of_pattern c index ([(Char.escaped c, index, h, n)]@acc) t (n+1)
```

I won't swear that this will fix all your problems. But without these parentheses, it looks like `acc` is being called as a function.

Comment: +1, but I think it's better to write `((Char.escaped c, index, h, n) :: acc)` rather than creating a single-element list and concatenating.